# Can not import cv2 in python 3 with Linux CentOS

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, centos

My Python version is 3.6.2, anaconda, with Linux CentOS

I use conda installed the opencv:

```
(py362) [cloudera@quickstart ~]$ conda list opencv

# packages in environment at /home/cloudera/anaconda3/envs/py362:
#
opencv                    3.2.0               np112py36_0    conda-forge
```

However, if I try to import the opencv, then I got the following ImportError:

```
ImportError: libopenblas.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Try to check if python version is compatible with the one of the opencv library you installed.

Comment: @AreTor I read from other threads, so I think, this installed opencv should work for python 3.  I also tried the other version `conda install -c menpo opencv3`, then I got `opencv3 with version 3.1.0`, however, if I import the opencv, `import cv2`, then I got the error message: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' `
`